# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Ads setDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, request, restkit

I'm having this error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when I click on the button "cadastrar" to register my new announcement of a aplicatiov to the database. I'm using restkit and my api is working the way I want.
someone has gone through this and know how to solve?

this is my NewAdViewController

```
#import "NewAdViewController.h"
#import "Ads.h"
#import "JVUtils.h"
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface NewAdViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewAdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (IBAction)signUp:(id)sender {


    if (self.titleField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa nos informar seu nome completo." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.priceField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa nos informar um e-mail para contato." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.localField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa criar uma senha para a sua conta." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else if (self.descriptionField.text.length <= 0) {
        [JVUtils showMessage:@"Você precisa confirmar sua senha." withTitle:@"Opa!"];
    } else {
            Ads *newAd = [Ads new];
            newAd.title = self.titleField.text;
            newAd.price = self.priceField.text;
            newAd.local = self.localField.text;
            newAd.description = self.descriptionField.text;


            [[JVWebService sharedService] setServiceDelegate:self];
            [[JVWebService sharedService] postAd:newAd];

        }
    }


- (void)successfulRequestDidReturnObject:(NSObject *)object {

    [JVUtils showMessage:@"Agora você tem uma conta JáVendi! Faça o login e desfrute ao máximo do aplicativo." withTitle:@"hadoukeeeen !"];

    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setCurrentUser:(User *)object];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void)requestDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [self.loadingIndicatorView stopAnimating];
    [JVUtils showMessage:error.localizedDescription withTitle:@"Erro"];
}


@end
```

this is my JVWebService:

```
#import "JVWebService.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JVUtils.h"
#import "Ads.h"

static NSString *kServerURL = @"http://localhost:3000";

@interface JVWebService ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) RKObjectManager *restKitObjectManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *adAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *postAdAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *userAttributes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *postUserAttributes;
@end

#define kSuccessStatusCode RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)

@implementation JVWebService

+ (instancetype)sharedService {
    static JVWebService *sharedService = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedService = [[self alloc] init];

        [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;
        sharedService.restKitObjectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kServerURL]];
        [sharedService.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] email]
                                                                                 password:[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] password]];
    });
    return sharedService;
}

#pragma mark - User

- (void)getUserForEmail:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    NSString *path = @"/users/sign_in.json";

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    User *user = [User new];
    user.email = email;
    user.password = password;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString] forKey:@"authencity_token"];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    [self.restKitObjectManager.HTTPClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:email password:password];
    [self.restKitObjectManager postObject:user path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation,
                                                                                     RKMappingResult *result){
        User *user = (User *)result.array.firstObject;
        user.password = password;
        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] login:user];

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] setLoggedViaFacebook:NO];

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:user];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    }

- (void)createUser:(User *)user{
    NSString *path = @"/users.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:user method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {}];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        User *user = (User *)result.array.firstObject;

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:user];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (void)updateUser:(User *)user withProfileImage:(UIImage *)profileImage {
    NSString *path = @"/users.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authencity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:user method:RKRequestMethodPATCH path:path parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

//                [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage)
//                                            name:@"user[avatar]"
//                                        fileName:@"profileImage.jpg"
//                                        mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] login:(User *) result.array.firstObject];
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:result.firstObject];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (void)logout {
    NSString *path = @"/users/sign_out.json";

    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:User.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.userAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postUserAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:User.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    NSDictionary *params = @{@"authenticity_token" : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authencity_token"]};

    [self.restKitObjectManager deleteObject:[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] currentUser] path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] logout];



        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}



- (void)sendResetPasswordInstructionsToEmail:(NSString *)email {
    NSString *path = @"/send_lost_password.json";

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email" : email};

    [self.restKitObjectManager getObject:nil path:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);

        if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
            [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
    }];
}




- (void)postAd:(Ads *)ad {
    NSString *path = @"/ads.json";
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:Ads.class];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.adAttributes];

    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:self.postAdAttributes];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                                   objectClass:Ads.class
                                                                                   rootKeyPath:@"ad"
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:objectMapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                       pathPattern:path
                                                                                           keyPath:@"ad"
                                                                                       statusCodes:kSuccessStatusCode];

    [self.restKitObjectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [self.restKitObjectManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:ad method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

//        NSArray *photosArray = ad.photos[0];
//        for(int i = 0; i < photosArray.count; i++) {
//            
//            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ad[photos_attributes][%i][picture]", i];
//            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo%i.jpg", i];
//            [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(photosArray[i])
//                                        name:name
//                                    fileName:fileName
//                                    mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
//        }
    }];

    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.restKitObjectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                                                               success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
                                                                                                   if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(successfulRequestDidReturnObject:)])
                                                                                                       [self.serviceDelegate successfulRequestDidReturnObject:nil];

                                                                                               } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                                                   if ([self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:)])
                                                                                                       [self.serviceDelegate requestDidFailWithError:error];
                                                                                               }];
    [self.restKitObjectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    [self.restKitObjectManager removeRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [self.restKitObjectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}



- (NSDictionary *)adAttributes {
    return @{
             @"id" : @"_id",
             @"title" : @"title",
             @"price" : @"price",
             @"local" : @"localization",
             @"description" : @"adDescription",
             @"categories" : @"categories",
             @"photos" : @"photos",
             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
             @"longitude" : @"longitude"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)postAdAttributes {
    return @{
             @"_id" : @"id",
             @"title" : @"title",
             @"price" : @"price",
             @"localization" : @"local",
             @"adDescription" : @"description",
             @"categories" : @"category_ids",
             @"user_id" : @"user_id",
             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
             @"longitude" : @"longitude"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)userAttributes {
    return @{
             @"id" : @"_id",
             @"email" : @"email",
             @"name" : @"name",
             @"avatar" : @"profileImageUrl",
             @"phone" : @"phone",
             @"password" : @"password",
             @"contact_pref" : @"communicationPreference",
             @"products_alerts" : @"productsAlerts"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)postUserAttributes {
    return @{
             @"_id" : @"id",
             @"email" : @"email",
             @"name" : @"name",
             @"phone" : @"phone",
             @"password" : @"password",
             @"password" : @"password_confirmation",
             @"communicationPreference" : @"contact_pref"
             };
}
@end
```

this is my ads.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Ads : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *local;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description;



@end
```

my post attributes:

```
- (NSDictionary *)adAttributes {
    return @{
             @"id" : @"_id",
             @"title" : @"title",
             @"price" : @"price",
             @"local" : @"localization",
             @"description" : @"especification",
//             @"categories" : @"categories",
//             @"photos" : @"photos",
//             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
//             @"longitude" : @"longitude"
             };
}

- (NSDictionary *)postAdAttributes {
    return @{
             @"id" : @"_id",
             @"title" : @"title",
             @"price" : @"price",
             @"local" : @"local",
             @"description" : @"especification",
//             @"categories" : @"category_ids",
//             @"user_id" : @"user_id",
//             @"latitude" : @"latitude",
//             @"longitude" : @"longitude"
             };
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in your `Ads` class where the description property is declared?

Comment: Yes. I posted my Ads.h.

Comment: I think your description property is probably clashing with the readonly description property on `NSObject`.  You should change the name of your property to something else or put `@synthesize description;` in your Ads.m file to force it to create a setter for you.

Comment: Really. By doing this the error changed and now this:  "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _id"

Comment: I've never used restkit but I would try swapping the order of your keys/values in your `postUserAttributes` and `postAdAttributes` dictionaries.

Comment: I posted them. I tried to make some alterations but not succeeded.

Comment: I could fix this part. Thanks for your help.